# Unable to install osgeo on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, osgeo

I'm trying to install `osgeo` both via poetry and pip but I see the same error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting osgeo
  Downloading osgeo-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.2 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: osgeo
  Building wheel for osgeo (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
      running install
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-qsmq6qut/osgeo_f8ba3b7216d1497cbed2acc160f87bd8/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 259, in run
          self.run_command('install')
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-qsmq6qut/osgeo_f8ba3b7216d1497cbed2acc160f87bd8/setup.py", line 27, in run
          raise Exception(error_msg)
      Exception: In order to be able to run `from osgeo import gdal`,
      You were probably trying to install `gdal` by running `pip install osgeo`.
      Instead, you should either `pip install gdal` or replace `osgeo` with `gdal` in your requirements.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for osgeo
  Running setup.py clean for osgeo
Failed to build osgeo
Installing collected packages: osgeo
  Running setup.py install for osgeo ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for osgeo did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      running install
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-qsmq6qut/osgeo_f8ba3b7216d1497cbed2acc160f87bd8/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-qsmq6qut/osgeo_f8ba3b7216d1497cbed2acc160f87bd8/setup.py", line 27, in run
          raise Exception(error_msg)
      Exception: In order to be able to run `from osgeo import gdal`,
      You were probably trying to install `gdal` by running `pip install osgeo`.
      Instead, you should either `pip install gdal` or replace `osgeo` with `gdal` in your requirements.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> osgeo

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I'm on Ubuntu 20.0 with Python 3.8.10. Below the pip3 list output:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- --------------------
apturl                 0.5.2
attrs                  19.3.0
beautifulsoup4         4.8.2
blinker                1.4
Brlapi                 0.7.0
certifi                2019.11.28
chardet                3.0.4
Click                  7.0
colorama               0.4.3
command-not-found      0.3
cryptography           2.8
cupshelpers            1.0
cycler                 0.10.0
dbus-python            1.2.16
decorator              4.4.2
defer                  1.0.6
distro                 1.4.0
distro-info            0.23ubuntu1
entrypoints            0.3
future                 0.18.2
GDAL                   3.0.4
html5lib               1.0.1
httplib2               0.14.0
idna                   2.8
importlib-metadata     1.5.0
ipython_genutils       0.2.0
Jinja2                 2.10.1
jsonschema             3.2.0
jupyter-core           4.6.3
keyring                18.0.1
kiwisolver             1.0.1
language-selector      0.1
launchpadlib           1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient     0.14.2
lazr.uri               1.0.3
louis                  3.12.0
lxml                   4.5.0
macaroonbakery         1.3.1
MarkupSafe             1.1.0
matplotlib             3.1.2
more-itertools         4.2.0
nbformat               5.0.4
netifaces              0.10.4
numpy                  1.17.4
oauthlib               3.1.0
olefile                0.46
OWSLib                 0.19.1
pexpect                4.6.0
Pillow                 7.0.0
pip                    22.0.4
plotly                 4.4.1
protobuf               3.6.1
psycopg2               2.8.4
pycairo                1.16.2
pycups                 1.9.73
Pygments               2.3.1
PyGObject              3.36.0
PyJWT                  1.7.1
pymacaroons            0.13.0
PyNaCl                 1.3.0
pyparsing              2.4.6
pyproj                 2.5.0
PyQt5                  5.14.1
pyRFC3339              1.1
pyrsistent             0.15.5
python-apt             2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.7
python-dateutil        2.7.3
python-debian          0.1.36ubuntu1
pytz                   2019.3
pyxdg                  0.26
PyYAML                 5.3.1
reportlab              3.5.34
requests               2.22.0
requests-unixsocket    0.2.0
retrying               1.3.3
scipy                  1.8.0
SecretStorage          2.3.1
setuptools             45.2.0
simplejson             3.16.0
sip                    4.19.21
six                    1.14.0
soupsieve              1.9.5
systemd-python         234
traitlets              4.3.3
ubuntu-advantage-tools 27.6
ubuntu-drivers-common  0.0.0
ufw                    0.36
unattended-upgrades    0.1
urllib3                1.25.8
usb-creator            0.3.7
wadllib                1.3.3
webencodings           0.5.1
wheel                  0.34.2
xkit                   0.0.0
zipp                   1.0.0
```

I've installed gdal and relative libraries following [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302161/949540), then:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev gdal-bin libgdal-dev
```

How I can solve this problem?
I need to use the function `read_shp` from [networkx](https://networkx.org/) but I can't because I see this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'
```

Comment: I think you might need to install `python3-gdal` too

Comment: I already have it @IanTurton ```python3-gdal is already the newest version (3.0.4+dfsg-1build3)```

Comment: Sounds a bit like paths are not being found correctly, and there is an issue that might potentially related. https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3735 Also try installing it globally, I have found that user installations are a bit fickle at times.

Comment: Did you find a solution? i am getting the same problem and would like to avoid an entirely new gdal install. Thanks,